# The pseudocode numbering start with 0 and continues to be zero

Tags: algorithms

im writing a pseudocode in ieee access template as below.

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{FVI (X, k, m, $\mu$)}
\label{alg:fvi}
\textbf{Input:} Dataset $X$, number of clusters $k$, weighting exponent $m$, and fuzzy membership values $\mu$.\\
\textbf{Output:} A new validity index,FVI
\hline
\begin{algorithmic}[1] % Start line numbering from 1
\For{each $C_l$}
    \For{each $X_i$}
        \State Calculate $\delta_{il}$ as Equation 5
        \State Calculate SDSC as Equation 8
        \State Calculate $\gamma_i$ as Equation 7
        \State Calculate $FVI$ as Equation 6
    \EndFor
\EndFor
\end{algorithmic}
\State Output the $FVI$
\end{algorithm}
```

The problem are:

1. i want the numbering start with 1 but the numbering start with 0
2. the numbering continuously 0

Please help to modify the code for numbering start from 1 and continue.

as the image:
[image]

Comment: Please extend your example to a complete minimal example such that we do not have to guess your setup.

Comment: Even if one adds the needed packages your code is full of errors. `\State` can only be used inside `algorithmic`. `\hline` cannot be used like you do here. And the two Input and Output should be a part of the algorithm. Fixing those and the numbers works just fine. Please don't just ignore compilation errors just because it generated a PDF